# Is there a way to quickly have a DerivedClass Constructor implement a BaseClass Constructor with default values?

Tags: c#

I have a BaseClass that has several parameters in it that lets you customize it, however, most of these parameters are optional and have default values assigned to it. This object has an abstract method that must be implemented. However, ideally I don't want to have to redefine all of the default parameters this class may have. I haven't found a real way to do it beyond just copying and pasting the BaseClass's constructor parameters into the DerivedClass.

So for example:

```
abstract class BaseClass {
    public BaseClass(int A, int B = 1, int C = 2, int D = 4) { /*BaseClass Implementation*/ }

    public abstract void AbstractMethod();
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass {
    public DerivedClass(int A, int B = 1, int C = 2, int D = 4)
    :base (A: A, B: B, C: C, D: D) {} //No new implementation in comparison to the BaseClass
    
    public void AbstractMethod() { /*Implementation*/ }
}
```

Note: As the project is growing right now, I'm playing it safe and using named parameters so as to not break code as I add on and decide to add required parameters

Ideally I would like to be able to do something like:

```
class DerivedClass : BaseClass {
     public DerivedClass() : base() {} // Base Class Implementation is used
}
```

Or at least some form of this so as to not have to redefine numerous default constructor values constantly. Is this at all possible or am I going to have to do it the way above?

Comment: No, there's nothing in C# to do this. You could potentially find some tooling that adds the constructor for you at the click of a mouse, but the code would still be there.

Comment: Visual Studio 2022 does have a "Generate Constructor" intellisense thingy. Create the class without a constructor and then right-click the class name  and select  *Quick actions and refactorings...* and choose *Generate constructor*.

Comment: If you really want to "play it safe", don't use default parameters at all, but overloads. The problem with default parameters is that the value used is filled in at the *caller* site, meaning that code that is compiled today will have the *current* values coded into it, even if a newer version has new values. Very occasionally this is what you actually want when versioning (so you can actually know what version the code was compiled against) but more often it's not, so especially for base classes default parameters that use any value other than `default` should be used sparingly, if at all.

Comment: An alternative to consider, if the parameters are used to initialize immutable properties (or if they can be rewritten that way), is to make them `init` instead (i.e. `class BaseClass { public int B { get; init; } = 4; }`). This avoids the problem with defaults appearing at the caller site while still leaving it up to callers to initialize if they want.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you for the tips, I'll look into where I can do default values, it's a point I should've considered but I didn't. `init` should actually work for most of my values as a lot of them are immutable properties already, and this would remove a lot of the overhead in my base class constructor.